# How to integrate only a variable in multivariate function in R?

Tags: r, vectorization, integral

I have the next function:

```
f <- function(x,y,z,w) {dpois(x, lambda = w*cos(y-z) ) }
```

I want to construct a function g(y,z,w) defined by the integral of f with respect to x. I can do it when I have two variables, the code is for example, something like this

```
margin <- function(y) { sapply(y, function(y) { integrate(function(x) f(x,y), llimx, ulimx)$value }) }
```

But I don't know how to do that for more than two variables.

Comment: 1.) Why not creating a variable inside the function that stores the `lambda` value, since it's always evaluated first and resulting in a constant, and then use what you know to integrate over the two variables (this variable and the `x`)?
2.) Have you known and tried `Vectorize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x,y,z,w) dpois(x, w*cos(y-z)),"x") 
g <- function(y,z,w) integrate(f, lower = 0, upper =Inf, y, z, w)
```